# Cannot retrieve data sent via js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use the following to send the data:

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
  var saveId = $(".my_post_id").attr("data-id");
  console.log(saveId);
  $.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    data :saveId, 
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(json_object) {
      console.log(json_object);
      $(".save_post").text("Data has been saved.");
    },
    error: function(json_object) {
      console.log(json_object);
      $(".save_post").text("Failed to save data !");
    }
  });
});
```

Console value when I do `console.log(saveId);` is **248**

And when I click the button to send the data, its text says: **Data has been saved.**

But when I open save.php i get an empty page.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $post_data = $_POST['data'];
    echo $post_data;
?>
```

All I am trying to do is to save a javascript variable in order to be able to retrieve it later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to send a key with the value:

```
data: { data: saveId }
```

You should also use the `data()` method to get `data-*` attributes, not `attr()`. Here's a full example:

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    data: { data: $(".my_post_id").data("id") }, 
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $(".save_post").text("Data has been saved.");
    },
    error: function(x, s, e) {
      $(".save_post").text("Failed to save data !");
    }
  });
});
```

Note that this is assuming you have only a single `.my_post_id` element. If you have multiple then `data-id` will only be read from the first one found in the DOM.

Also, there's no such thing as a 'JSON object'. The argument provided to the `success` handler is an object (or array) which has been deserialised from the JSON formatted string in the response.

Similarly, the `error` handler doesn't accept an argument which contains JSON, so that signature is incorrect. I'd suggest checking the [jQuery $.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) if you are unsure on what arguments are available to which jQuery AJAX handlers.

Comment: actually yes, I would need to send different ids and keep a track of these in save.php, how to?

Comment: That would depend entirely on how how `.save_post` relates to `.my_post_id`. DOM traversal is the best solution to that. If you want a code example to show you how to do it, please start a new question which contains the JS you're using as well as the HTML.

Comment: .my_post_id will be set on each different page I land, i should do a check if the key is present already as we might end on the same page few times, to we won't be saving the same key. To be honest I was more working with localStorage, then I thought to go down the php route and i just complicated the whole thing. Anyway, your code works yet when I go to the save.php page a get a blank page

Comment: That's normal behaviour. When you open `save.php` in your browser you send a GET request with no parameters. It will only work from the AJAX which sends a POST request

Comment: I am doing     `echo $post_data;` tho thought to retrieve the var like that

Comment: Yes, because when you visit the URL through the browser you send a GET request, not a POST, as I stated above

Comment: If you really wanted, but it won't change anything.

Comment: how would you see the data then? A link to read about it would be fine, thanks

Comment: Your `console.log()` in the `success` will show you the returned value, or you can see it in the console. Sending a GET request through the browser in an attempt to see a page which is expecting a POST request is never going to work.

Comment: Right so the whole approach is wrong i guess, all I am trying to do is save some variables (unique), to a php and retrieve them on a call in js

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `save some variables (unique), to a php`, as PHP is stateless and nothing can be saved to it for later retrieval. I'd strongly suggest you start a new question explaining exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok got it you've just clarified actually a confusion i had. I might save it to a text file or go back to localStorage all together! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send JSON data so that php can retrive the same data using key

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
var saveId = $(".my_post_id").attr("data-id");
console.log(saveId);
$.ajax({
url: "save.php",
data : {'data':saveId}, // Add object
type: 'POST',
success: function(json_object) {
  console.log(json_object);
  $(".save_post").text("Data has been saved.");
},
error: function(json_object) {
  console.log(json_object);
  $(".save_post").text("Failed to save data !");
}
```

});
});

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
$post_data = $_POST;
echo $post_data;
```

It will works for you.

Comment: this gives me: Array

Comment: can you please paste here all output?

Comment: I only see: "Array"